# Updating two components with same props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I created a `Range` component, (which uses `<input type='range'/>` under the hood). It takes a `rangeValueState` prop used to update the value of the component. `rangeValueState` is nothing but a state that can be destructured as `[rangeValue, setRangeValue]`.

My parent component has a `settings` state which is an object that holds many key-value pairs, with one such being `'rangeValue': 500`. Let the parent component be `A`. `A` renders `B`, `B` renders two `C` Components side by side. `C` component renders a `form` element, which has a `Range` component in it as well.

So, the overall output is two forms (left and right), and each form has a `Range` component each.
I had to add a functionality, where when a change in either of the `Range` Component happens, it should update the `rangeValue` in the `settings` object and vice versa, and should also update the same value in the other `Range` component. Therefore, my Component `C` has the following code:

```
    // Use the custom hook initialize range value state, and access realtime state.
    const rangeValueState = useRangeValue(settings.rangeValue);
    const [rangeValue, setRangeValue] = rangeValueState;

    // Update the rangeValue on update in settings
    useEffect(() => { setRangeValue(settings.rangeValue) }, [settings.rangeValue]);
    
    // Update the settings on update in rangeValue
    useEffect(() => { setSettings({ ...settings, rangeValue }) }, [rangeValue]);
```

As, you can see it results is an infinite loop. (But, no doubt it would work fine)
It works but this is a case of `<input type="range"/>` under the hood. If I slide the range from, say, 1 to 500, it would call the `setState` function so many times (which is asynchronous), because it uses `onChange` to update the value resulting in an infinite loop and when I stop sliding the range input, it just oscillates between two last values (see the gif below).

[image: Range Component oscillating]

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Consider managing the state in component `B`. Pass update functions and the value from `B` into the `C` components. When either range slider in `C` is updated, the update should handle updating the state and `settings`. I cannot give a more concrete solution since you have omitted so much of your code.

Comment: @Wongjn , `C` is a form, and it actually has many more components, and all their states are managed by the `settings` which it gets from its parents. Managing the state, of only the Range Components in a different way than others, would make it less organized as I would have to pass a state from B to C to Range Components to handle them.